# Python Requests Params

Tags: python, post, python-requests

I'm working with a script that downloads comments from YouTube. The script isn't using the API, it is scraping the comments by using Python's Requests module & lxml. My question is, how do you find out what parameters you can use when sending a POST request?

Below are the params used to send in the request.

```
        params = {'action_load_comments': 1,
                  'order_by_time': True,
                  'filter': youtube_id}
```

Comment: It's not always straight forward. You'll have to inspect the request made by your browser. I haven't tried this for YouTube, so it may be simple.

Comment: @SuperStew Yeah sadly I'm not seeing it. Hmmm... I mean the script I'm using works swimmingly, but I don't understand what params the original writer knew to use.

Comment: some params has useful names and you know what for it is. Other you have to check - "what will happen if I don't use this param or I change it  ie. I add 1 to number"